# Fragment is not showing anymore after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application there is a main menu which is presented by a Fragment. When I click a Button the main menu Fragment is replaced by a second Fragment to show the requested content. There is also a backwards navigation via Back Stack.

All this works perfectly fine until I rotate the screen and click the button. Somehow then the second Fragment does not show anymore although the onStart() method of the second fragment is called. What remains is just the main menu layout on the screen.

This is the code within the onclick() method:

```
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    boolean notExists = (newEntryFragment == null);

    if(notExists || fm.findFragmentByTag(NewEntryFragment.class.getName())== null){
        if(notExists)
        newEntryFragment = new NewEntryFragment();

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newEntryFragment , NewEntryFragment.class.getName());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }

    else if(newEntryFragment.isHidden()){
        ft.show(newEntryFragment).commit();
    }
```

This is how I restore my Activity:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Log.d("MyActivity" , "savedInstance is not null");
        newEntryFragment = (NewEntryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NewEntryFragment.class.getName());
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    createMainMenu();

  }

 public void createMainMenu(){
    mainMenuFragment = new MainMenuFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, mainMenuFragment);

        ft.commit();
}
```

Second Fragment code:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_entry, container, false);

    return view;
}

  @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
    myActivity.setTitle("New Entry");
    myActivity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

Is there maybe anything else that I need to restore? Maybe the fragment_container ?

I don't receive any errors when this happens.

Comment: Could you post your fragment class code? Are you using: setRetainInstance(true) within your fragment? Are you sure your fragment transaction code is executed after orientation change?

Comment: Yes, I use that. And the ActionBar title changes to "New Entry" when I click the Button that is how I know that the Fragment onStart() method is called.

Comment: Does createMainMenu() actually perform the fragment transaction? When you re-orient your device, the activity is destroyed and rebuilt, so you have to make sure a) your fragment is found and b) you perform a FragmentTransaction to update your container. From your description, it sounds like the latter isn't happening.

Comment: you are right I just found out I use add() insted of replace() in the createMainMenu()

Comment: okay do you know a proper way to implement that what you just explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved my own problem.

I just need to restore the Activity like this:

```
    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 if(savedInstanceState != null){
    Log.d("MyActivity" , "savedInstance is not null");
    newEntryFragment = (NewEntryFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NewEntryFragment.class.getName());
}else{createMainMenu();
 }

setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
 }
```

So the MainMenu is not created again everytime it rotates.